# Issue with Karma runner executing test cases

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am developing an application which uses Karma as testing tool for executing test cases. The problem is when I try to execute test cases it isn't executing any tests rather it just stuck at a point. When I use this command

```
grunt test --force
```

I am getting this result

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task

Running "compass:server" (compass) task

Done, without errors.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Warning: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings Used --force, continuing.

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

After that no progress, it just stuck here. Here is my `karma.conf.js` file

```
// Karma configuration

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';
 module.exports = function(config) {
   config.set({
     frameworks: ['jasmine']
   });
 };
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/ng-grid/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js',
  'bower_components/ng-grid/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
  'bower_components/momentjs/moment.js',
  'bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.js',
  'bower_components/toastr/toastr.js',
  'app/*.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  '../sinonjs/test.js'
];

// list of files to exclude
exclude = ['app/out.js'];

preprocessors = {
  'app/*.js': 'coverage',
  'app/**/*.js': 'coverage'
};

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
// for test coverage2 
reporters = ['progress', 'coverage'];
coverageReporter = {
  type : 'html',
  dir : 'coverage/'
}

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
//reporters = ['progress'];

// web server port
port = 8080;

// cli runner port
runnerPort = 9100;

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors = true;

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
//logLevel = LOG_INFO;

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch = false;

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers = ['Chrome'];

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout = 5000;

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun = false;
```

What might be the issue here?

When I added a `logLevel` configuration in my `karma.conf.js` file I got the following result

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task

Running "compass:server" (compass) task

Done, without errors.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Warning: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings Used --force, continuing.

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-chrome
-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-coffee
-preprocessor.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-firefo
x-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-html2j
s-preprocessor.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-jasmin
e.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-phanto
mjs-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-requir
ejs.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin E:\wamp\www\balto4forms\node_modules/karma-script
-launcher.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        E:/wamp/www/balto4forms/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
        E:/wamp/www/balto4forms/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
```

Comment: Try adding the [logLevel](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html) configuration option to your karma.conf.js.

Comment: When I add the line logLevel = LOG_INFO; i got the warning WARN [config]: LOG_INFO is not supported anymore.
  Please use `config.LOG_INFO` instead and stuck at same line as above

Comment: I think it's telling you to add a line like this to your config: `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` (note you may want the debug output to get the most details)

Comment: Still the test cases isn't executing

Comment: That wasn't supposed to fix anything :) it was so you could try and figure out what is wrong. Do you get any extra output as a result?

Comment: Updated the question. Please check.

Comment: The section where it shows the "Resolved files:" is where you would expect it to list all of the source/test files it's finding (the things that you put into the files array in the config). Make sure you are specifying the right paths/basePath, etc.

Comment: There isn't any problem with the paths.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it myself by wrapping up all the configuration settings under the `module.exports` function. Now my `karma.conf.js` file will look like this;

```
// Karma configuration

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude

 module.exports = function(config) {
   config.set({
   basePath : '',
     frameworks: ['jasmine'],
     logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files : [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/ng-grid/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js',
  'bower_components/ng-grid/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
  'bower_components/momentjs/moment.js',
  'bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.js',
  'bower_components/toastr/toastr.js',
  'app/*.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  '../sinonjs/test.js'
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude : ['app/out.js'],

preprocessors : {
  'app/*.js': 'coverage',
  'app/**/*.js': 'coverage',
},

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
// for test coverage2 
reporters : ['progress', 'coverage'],
coverageReporter : {
  type : 'html',
  dir : 'coverage/'
},

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: dots || progress || growl
//reporters : ['progress'];

// web server port
port : 8080,

// cli runner port
runnerPort : 9100,

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors : true,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
//logLevel : LOG_INFO;

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch : false,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers : ['Chrome'],

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout : 5000,

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun : false
   });
 };
```

Now all the test cases are executing fine.